# What does “for” mean in “want a clown for a dad”?

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions

I’m watching Modern Family, and it’s the conversation of Cam and Mitchell

> Mitchell: We need somebody to pump some life back into this party.
>
> Cam: I got this.
>   I'll go in and turn on some music, bring out the cupcakes, pump up the bubble machine. Or Is that a roundabout way of saying a certain clown can come to the party?
>
> Mitchell: I was wrong.
>   Every kid wants a clown for a dad.

So Cam wanted to play as a clown for his daughter but Mitchel didn’t want, and then he changed his mind.

Here, “every kid wants a clown for a dad”, what does “for” mean?
If possible, could you give me the definition from a dictionary?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to help in knowing what you are already comfortable with, does "I want steak for dinner" make sense to you?

Comment: @cobaltduck  Yes 

Comment: In the cited context, ***for = [in order] to serve the purpose of [being]***. Thus *I want steak **for** dinner* means *I want my dinner to be steak*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "for" has many meanings in English- "for" and "of" are perhaps two of the most overused and abused words, so it is understandable to have some confusion.  Out of the several defintions and sub-definitions [given at Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for), I think we want 2a here:

> 2a : as being or constituting
>   // taken *for* a fool  //eggs *for* breakfast

There are many things a kid would want his father to be, or qualities he would want his father to have.  A father who is a clown or who can act like a clown when appropriate, is a nice kind of father to have.

Answer (score 0):

**for** there means "serving in the role of".

> He's using a coffee mug for a wine glass.
>
> The office provided him a table for a desk.

So, to "have a clown for a dad" means "a clown serving in the role of dad".